# ParseExact with counter of hour from 0 to 23

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime, format

I have some issue in converting string to date using `ParseExact`

```
string _date = " 2014-06-23-12:40:18 "
DateTime dateresult = DateTime.ParseExact(
_date.Trim(),
"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
DateTimeStyles.None)
```

The `dateresult`'s value is **23/06/2014 00:40:18**. The problem is that the resulting datetime's hour is 0 not 12!!! I need to keep the normal hour counter from 0 to 23

- How can i change my code to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`HH` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) instead of `hh`

```
DateTime dateresult = DateTime.ParseExact(_date.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use `H` specifier because OP wants to get `0` to `23`, not `00` to `23`?

Comment: yes,probably it will be better.but the question is not perfectly clear, for now it looks like he just want to fix the issue and get the  hour correctly. he doesn't say anything about whether he wants to display hour as 02:20 or 2:20

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code like this. Instead of hh, use HH for 24 hour format

```
string _date = " 2014-06-23-12:40:18 ";
DateTime dateresult = DateTime.ParseExact(_date.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`hh` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for *12-hour clock* which is `01` to `12`.

Use [`H` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#H_Specifier)  which is for *24-hour clock* which is `0` to `23`.

> The "H" custom format specifier represents the hour as a number from 0
>   through 23; that is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour
>   clock that counts the hours since midnight. A single-digit hour is
>   formatted without a leading zero.

```
string _date = "2014-06-23-12:40:18";
DateTime dateresult = DateTime.ParseExact(_date.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd-H:mm:ss", 
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```